How do I compute confidence intervals for the predicted difference in cumulative risks from a survival model?
I have the following data:
library(cobalt)
library(tidycmprsk)
library(ggsurvfit)
library(gtsummary)

set.seed(123)
lalonde <- cbind(lalonde, 
            event = sample(c(0, 1), size = 614, replace = TRUE, 
              prob = c(0.84, 0.16)), 
            time = runif(614, min = 10, max = 365))
n <- ceiling(0.05 * nrow(lalonde))  
selected_indices <- sample(1:nrow(lalonde), size = n)
lalonde[selected_indices, "event"] <- 2

lalonde$event <- factor(lalonde$event, levels = c(0, 1, 2),
                        labels = c("Censored", "Event1", "Event2"))

And I can derive absolute risks from the cumulative incidence function:
p <- cuminc(Surv(time, event) ~ treat, lalonde) %>% 
  tbl_cuminc(
    times = c(180, 230),
    label_header = "**{time}-day cuminc**") 

which gives:
Characteristic  180-day cuminc  230-day cuminc
treat   

    0   8.1% (5.6%, 11%)    14% (11%, 19%)
    1   9.1% (5.3%, 14%)    13% (8.2%, 20%)

How can I calculate the risk difference with confidence intervals for the specified time-points?

You might get a specific approach by following the example of https://stacks.cdc.gov/view/cdc/22757/cdc_22757_DS11.pdf. It's not hard to find the associated files that this tutorial assumes you have access to. Post a comment to me if that proves problematic.

You could use the nonparametric block bootstrap to fit models to many datasets, calculate the difference between the two absolute risks for each dataset, then summarize the distribution of the difference using whatever interval you want. There are many variants of the bootstrap that require stronger/weaker assumptions for correct coverage.
You can also use the delta method to get the standard error of the difference in predictions then construct e.g. a 95% confidence intervals around the difference. This requires the model's covariance matrix. I don't know what model you are actually running due to unfamiliarity with the software, but it looks like you can extract this with vcov() from the actual model calls underlying your call to cuminc(). Since the functions you're using to get "tidy" output are essentially wrappers around the models that do not provide access to all of the output, you'll need to swap out your function calls for access to the outputted covariance matrix.

I attempted to run vcov on the intermediate result from the cuminc call and got a message saying there was no such method for items of classes "c('tidycuminc', 'hardhat_model', 'hardhat_scalar')". On the other hand I found a tutorial that described a method for calculating CI's around differences in subdistributions of cumulative incidence. Posted above.

Yes, I meant the intermediate outputs that are internal. There is no vcov method for those objects, but there may be an argument to return the cov matrix when e.g. coxph is specified. The subdistribution hazard model isn't what you fit.

coxph doesn't model risk differences.

I'm not sure why you believe this. It's straightforward to get absolute risk, cumulative risk, and difference in either across covariates from a proportional hazards model.

coxph models proportional hazards, i.e. relative risk or risk ratios. It is true that you could construct a risk estimate and you could then take differences. But that is different than modeling differences.

You are conflating estimating a single parameter versus modeling but this is outside of the scope of the OP's question.

A Cox proportional model has a linear form on the right and a log hazard on the left.  On the untransformed scale it is multiplicative. It does much more and assumes much more than estimate single parameters. It’s not well suited for the linear additive model that would be statistically appropriate for estimating risk differences.

You are now confused about additivity...

I suppose it's possible that I'm confused but your assertion of that claim is unconvincing.

You could use the adjustedCurves R package to do this automatically. The package is primarily meant to do this for adjusted cumulative incidences, but it also supports non-parametric estimation. In your example:
library(cobalt)
library(ggsurvfit)
library(gtsummary)
library(adjustedCurves)

set.seed(123)
lalonde <- cbind(lalonde, 
                 event = sample(c(0, 1), size = 614, replace = TRUE, 
                                prob = c(0.84, 0.16)), 
                 time = runif(614, min = 10, max = 365))
n <- ceiling(0.05 * nrow(lalonde))  
selected_indices <- sample(1:nrow(lalonde), size = n)
lalonde[selected_indices, "event"] <- 2

lalonde$treat <- factor(lalonde$treat)

# estimate the cumulative incidence functions for cause = 1
# here, method="aalen_johansen" means that the cuminc() function will be
# used internally
adjcif <- adjustedcif(data=lalonde,
                      variable="treat",
                      event="event",
                      ev_time="time",
                      method="aalen_johansen",
                      conf_int=TRUE,
                      cause=1)

# get the difference + confidence interval
adjusted_curve_diff(adjcif, times=c(180, 230), conf_int=TRUE)

Details on how the estimation works are given in the documentation of the package.
